# Repetitively multiplying digits of a number

Tags: number-theory

I am looking at the following problem.  To begin with, I will introduce the terminology that I use in the statement of my question.  
Suppose we have an $n$-digit positive integer $x$, (we do not count leading 0s before the decimal point nor trailing 0s after the decimal point).  For reference, call the product of the digits of $x$ the ''(first) digit product of $x$."  If $n=1$, the digit product of $x$ is $x$.  We can iterate the procedure and derive the digit product of the digit product of $x$; call this result the ''second digit product of $x$."  We define the ''$k$th digit product of $x$" recursively as the digit product of the $(k-1)$th digit product of $x$.  We call the smallest $k$ for which the $k$th digit product of $x$ is a single digit the ''digit product stopping time of $x$" and the corresponding $k$th digit product the ''digit product limit of $x$.

As an example, the digit product limit and stopping time of 77 are 8 and 4 respectively (77 $\rightarrow$ 49 $\rightarrow$ 36 $\rightarrow$ 18 $\rightarrow$ 8).  Among all $n$-digit numbers, what is the maximum digit product stopping time (as a function of $n$)?  It seems for 2-digit numbers, the maximum stopping time is 4 (which applies for 77), but I am not sure about larger numbers.  Also, it seems that for numbers with relatively large stopping times, the associated limit is 8.  
I guess this makes intuitive sense since among single digit numbers (which the limit must be), other than 6, 8 has the most distinct factor pairs (1 and 8, 2 and 4).  Unlike 6, however, all four of the 2-digit numbers that result from concatenating the elements in the factor pairs (i.e. 18, 81, 24, 42) are composite numbers.  In this regard, my second question is will the digit product limit of the number(s) with the max stopping time among n-digit numbers always be 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the digit product stopping time. Since appending the digit one to a number does not change the product of its digits, we have $f(x)\le f(x+1)$.
The following is the result of numeric computation. I have considered only numbers with digits $2,\dots,9$.
$$\begin{align}
f(2)&=4,\quad x=77\\
f(3)&=5,\quad x= 679,688\\
f(4)&=6,\quad x= 6788\\
f(5)&=7,\quad x= 679,688\\
f(6)&=7,\quad x= 238889,\dots\\
f(7)&=8,\quad x= 2677889,\dots\\
f(8)&=9,\quad x= 26888999,\dots\\
f(9)&=9,\quad x= 223888999,\dots\\
\end{align}$$
The digit product limit of all the numbers with maximum stopping time for $n\ge4$ is $0$.